# React-Navigation: How to pass data between tabs in TabNavigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I Have two tabs in tabNavigation

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeView
});

const SettingStack = createStackNavigator({
    Setting: SettingView
});

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: HomeStack,
    Setting: SettingStack
});
```

So I want to switch tab from `HomeView` to `SettingView`

#### // IN HOME VIEW

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Setting', {
    someFlag: true,
    data: "SET"
});
```

via button action and want to send some data as below.

#### // IN SETTING VIEW

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const openPCPSchedule = navigation.getParam("someFlag", false);
const data = navigation.getParam("data", null);
console.log("NAVI PARAMS: ", openPCPSchedule); // false
console.log("NAVI data: ", data); // null
```

Getting `false` and `null` at `SettingView`, Need a correct way to get data from one to tab to other?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `dangerouslyGetParent()` in SettingView. `this.props.navigation.navigate` sends params to the parent, not to the screen.
The code in SettingView will be:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const openPCPSchedule = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().getParam("someFlag", false);
const data = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().getParam("data", null);
```

Comment: Reason why the function is called dangerouslyGetParent is to warn developers against overusing it to eg. get parent of parent and other hard-to-follow patterns. [reactnavigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-key.html#usage-with-reset-navigation-actionshtml-reset)

Comment: `TypeError: navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().getParam is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

We get props from previous tab using this.props.navigation.

While passing data add

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Setting', {
    someFlag: true,
    data: "SET"
});
```

To access above data on Setting screen  add following code in componentDidMount method or in render method

`this.props.navigation.state.params.someFlag` // You can access someFlag as true here

Answer (score 1):

You can use `screenProps`

`ScreenProps` Usage [Link Page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html)

- screenProps - Pass down extra options to child screens

**//MAIN VIEW**

```js
class YourApp extends Component {
  render() {
    const screenProps = {
         someFlag: true,
         data: "SET"
    }

    return (
      <TabNavigator screenProps={screenProps} />
    )
  }
}

export default YourApp

AppRegistry.registerComponent('YourApp', () => YourApp);
```

**// IN SETTING VIEW**

```js
class SettingScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation, screenProps } = this.props

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{screenProps.someFlag}</Text>
        <Text>{screenProps.data}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```